# how to increase color intensity in colorramppalette

Tags: r

I am using pheatmap package in R for making heatmaps on different kinds data..and using colorramppalette for making colors but the colors are very bright.

i want some dark colors,how can i do that?

here is the code:

```
hmcols<-colorRampPalette(c("white","red"))(256)

pheatmap(
  test,
  color=hmcols,
  cluster_rows=FALSE,
  cluster_cols=FALSE,
  legend=TRUE,
  show_rownames=FALSE,
  show_colnames=FALSE,
  filename="a.png"
)
```

how can i increase color intensity in colorramppalette or can i use any other heatmap package that is similar to pheatmap but produce dark color?

Comment: i tried that..for example i want like this http://genome.cshlp.org/content/21/2/245/F2.large.jpg

Comment: You might want to read [**the about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. StackOverflow is made **much** more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little check mark or upvote it. You are under absolutely **no** obligation to do so, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem and helps to keep the site clean by removing answered question from the unanswered questions stack. If u need further colour advice pls ask

Answer (score 6):

Try using `hcl` and adjusting the luminance steps. For example:

```
cols <- hcl(0,l=seq(1,100,length=11))
cols
# [1] "#3F0000" "#470016" "#591D2D" "#6F3744" "#87505B" "#A06974" "#BB838D" "#D69DA8"
# [9] "#F1B8C3" "#FFD4DE" "#FFF0FB"
plot(1:11,cex=4,bg=cols,pch=21)
```

There are a lot of examples under `?hcl` and I am sure you will find some colour breaks that suit your needs.

If that doesn't suit your needs, you could also use some of the colour scales found under the `RColorBrewer` package, which I highly recommend (check out their [**excellent website**](http://colorbrewer2.org/) for more colour scales), and interpolate colours using `colorRampPalette` with `brewer.pal` and perhaps truncating the end of the colour scale.

You could also use a diverging colour scale, again from `RColorBrewer` as opposed to a sequential one. So here are some examples:

```
require(RColorBrewer)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

cols <- colorRampPalette( colors = hcl(0,l=seq(1,100,length=11)) )
plot( 1:11 , cex = 4 , bg = cols(11) , pch = 21 , main = "HCL Colours")

cols <- colorRampPalette( colors = rev(brewer.pal(9,"Reds")) )
plot( 1:11 , cex = 4 , bg = cols(11) , pch = 21 , main = "Sequential RColorBrewer palette")

cols <- colorRampPalette( colors = rev(brewer.pal(9,"Reds"))[1:5] )
plot( 1:11 , cex = 4 , bg = cols(11) , pch = 21 , main = "Truncated sequential\nRColorBrewer palette" )

cols <- colorRampPalette( colors = brewer.pal(9,"RdBu") )
plot( 1:11 , cex = 4 , bg = cols(11) , pch = 21 , main = "Diverging RColorBrewer palette" )
```

[image]